# Web scraping in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application which currently uses `http.get` to get JSON data from an API. This works great.

I'm wondering if I can pass a [static webpage URL](https://www.google.com/#q=stack+overflow), and scrape the results using the response from `http.get`?

I've seen tutorials on web scraping with [Node](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) and JavaScript libraries like [ScraperJS](https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs), but I haven't been able to successfully use these in an Angular (client-side) application. Is there anyway to use a JavaScript web scraping library in Angular?

Comment: I think you might run into a number of security issues when doing that. Do you have a reason why you wouldn't want to do that on the server?

Comment: One of the neatest ways to scrape HTML without having to set up your own server side code is to use YQL with an XPath conditional statement.  This can return either JSON data or XML, which can then be manipulated client side.

Comment: @sideroxylon  can you elaborate a bit on this ? maybe a sample code ?

Comment: @Xsmael It's been a while since I looked at this, but first you need to set up a query like this: `query = 'select * from html WHERE url = "[target site]" AND xpath = "[xpath query]";`. Then create a request URL, like this: `url = ''http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=xml'`.  Then put it together: `$.getJSON(url + '&callback=?', function (data) {`.  Take a look at what you get in `data`.  Just make sure you get your xpath query right.  More [HERE](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do so because this has nothing to do with Angular at all. Client-side JavaScript is just that. It runs on the client. What you need to do involves making an HTTP call for request URL and retrieving the HTML from a site, then parsing that HTML for various meta-data. That needs to be done via a server-side call to the site to load the data from the remote site.